# Automatic layout of DAG diagram

Tags: d3.js, directed-acyclic-graphs

I need an algorithm to layout topologically sorted DAG similar to how my [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/AdvRider/137ozkmg/3/) shows.

Is there any open source library that can do that? What are my options?

[image]

At the moment it's just a simple manual calculation of X and Y coordinates:

```
var nodes = [
    {label: 'A', x:     constant, y: 255, width:70, height:50 }, 
    {label: 'B', x: 2.5*constant, y: 410, width:70, height:50 },
    {label: 'C', x: 2.5*constant, y: 255, width:70, height:50 },
    {label: 'D', x: 4.0*constant, y: 255, width:70, height:50 },
    {label: 'E', x: 2.5*constant, y: 100, width:70, height:50 },
    {label: 'F', x: 4.0*constant, y: 100, width:70, height:50 }
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this sort of thing with [d3-graphviz](https://github.com/magjac/d3-graphviz). There are plenty of options for styling and several different layout engines. This is pretty close to yours:

```js
let dotSource = `graph{
  rankdir = LR;
  node [
    style=filled;
    fillcolor=steelblue;
    fontcolor=white;
    shape=box
  ]
  A -- B;
  A -- C;
  A -- E;
  C -- D;
  C -- E;
  E -- F;
}`
d3.select("#graph").graphviz()
    .renderDot(dotSource);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/7.8.2/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3-graphviz/5.0.2/d3-graphviz.min.js"></script>
<div id="graph" style="text-align: center;"></div>
```